Using the weak formulation, find the function $u$ that satisfies this boundary-value problem.
This exercise is paraphrased from page 8 of Finite Elements: An Introduction Volume 1 (Becker, Cary, Oden). The problem is split into three sub-parts, and I have attempted to already solve the prior two parts of the problem.

The identity function is defined by $\mathbf I (x) = x$. Concatenating functions will be the Hadamard product (matching, element-wise multiplication of image points), rather than composition.
$H$ is the space of all functions of form $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that are smooth, square integrable, and vanish on the endpoints. Have $u, v \in H$. Solve for $u$ such that$$-u'' = \mathbf I $$
and the weak formulation
$$ \int \limits_0^1 (-uv'' - \mathbf I v) \,dx = 0 \;\;\;\; \text{for all } v \in H$$
is satisfied.

Answer: Function $u$ vanishes at the endpoints, so we have by a trivial application of product rule that $$\int \limits_0^1 u v'' \, dx = \int \limits_0^1 -u' v' \, dx$$ Accordingly, the weak formulation can be rewritten as $$ \int \limits_0^1 (u'v' - \mathbf I) v \,dx = 0$$ which from the second part of this problem gives $$u = {\mathbf I - \mathbf I^3\over 6} $$

The overall structure of this problem appears to be inductive; you can rephrase one weak formulation in terms of the weak formulation of the previous problem statement, which through induction gives us the solution to the base case. Does this inductive solution yield the right result?
